# Como podría obtener la suma de las camas ocupadas por tipo de servicio para un mes en SqlServer

Tags: sql, select, subconsultas

Tabla servicios

[image: Tabla Servicios]

Tabla Atenciones hospitalarias

[image: Tabla Atencion Estancia Hospitalaria]

***-- Se necesita obtener la suma de camas ocupadas por dia de un mes, por cada servicio***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-- camas ocupadas del día 01/08/2022 del servicio 313 del día

```
select * from AtencionesEstanciaHospitalaria where IdServicio=313 and 
        (FechaDesocupacion>'20220801' and
        FechaOcupacion<='20220801')
```

Este query solo me arroja la suma de un servicio, como lo haría para todo los servicios

```
declare
@fec_inicio DateTime = '20220801',
@fec_fin DateTime = '20220831',
@total INT=0
declare @tabla_totales TABLE(idserv INT,total int)
    while(@fec_inicio<=@fec_fin)
            BEGIN
            set @Idservicio=313
            set @total=@total+(select COUNT(*) AS NUM from AtencionesEstanciaHospitalaria 
                    where IdServicio=@Idservicio and 
                    FechaDesocupacion>@fec_inicio and
                    FechaOcupacion<=@fec_inicio
                    )               
            set @fec_inicio=DATEADD(DAY,1,@fec_inicio)
    END     
            insert into @tabla_totales
            select @Idservicio,@total
select * from @tabla_totales
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es mucho más sencilla de lo que parece. Solo necesitas sumar los días sin tener que recorrer fecha por fecha. Solo tenemos que obtener los días contenidos en cada periodo de atención limitado por la fecha inicial y final de la consulta, para después sumar esos valores.

```
DECLARE @IdServicio int = 313,
        @fec_inicio DateTime = '20220801',
        @fec_fin    DateTime = '20220831';

SELECT IdServicio,
        --Si inicia antes de la fecha inicial, cambiamos por la fecha inicial del periodo
       CASE WHEN FechaOcupacion < @fec_inicio THEN @fec_inicio ELSE FechaOcupacion END,
       --Si termina después de la fecha final, cambiamos por la fecha final del periodo más uno para que cuente esa noche
       CASE WHEN FechaDesocupacion > @fec_fin THEN DATEADD( DD, 1, @fec_fin) ELSE FechaDesocupacion END,
       --Obtenemos la diferencia de días en los periodos definidos por las dos columnas anteriores.
       DATEDIFF( DD,
                    CASE WHEN FechaOcupacion < @fec_inicio THEN @fec_inicio ELSE FechaOcupacion END,
                    CASE WHEN FechaDesocupacion > @fec_fin THEN DATEADD( DD, 1, @fec_fin) ELSE FechaDesocupacion END) AS Dias
FROM AtencionesEstanciaHospitalaria
WHERE FechaOcupacion <= @fec_fin
AND FechaDesocupacion >= @fec_inicio;
```

Ahí podemos ver el detalle de los días, solo necesitamos sumarlos y reducir los datos innecesarios.

```
SELECT IdServicio,
        SUM(
            DATEDIFF( DD,
                    CASE WHEN FechaOcupacion < @fec_inicio THEN @fec_inicio ELSE FechaOcupacion END,
                    CASE WHEN FechaDesocupacion > @fec_fin THEN DATEADD( DD, 1, @fec_fin) ELSE FechaDesocupacion END)) AS Dias
FROM AtencionesEstanciaHospitalaria
WHERE FechaOcupacion    <= @fec_fin
AND   FechaDesocupacion >= @fec_inicio
GROUP BY IdServicio;
```

Sin bucles, sin procesar fila por fila y mucho más simple que las otras soluciones y más rápida también.

Answer (score -1):

Entiendo que cada registro de la tabla AtencionesEstanciaHospitalaria corresponde a la internación de un paciente en un servicio.

Asumo que si la fecha y hora de desocupación son nulas, significa que el paciente todavía se encuentra internado (no ha sido dado de alta), por lo tanto cuando la fecha de desocupación es nula en la query la reemplazaré por la fecha actual.

Hay que tener en cuenta que un paciente puede permanecer internado por varios meses, incluso podría permanecer internado de un año a otro.

También puede ocurrir que en un día una misma cama sea ocupada por mas de una persona, como no hay información de que cama ocupa que paciente, si un día dos pacientes ocuparon la misma cama (uno en la mañana, y otro en la tarde), se contabilizará como dos camas ocupadas (aunque es la misma cama).

**Para obtener la cantidad de camas ocupadas en el mes en cada servicio:**

En este caso utilizo una query "recursiva" con la cual para cada registro de la tabla AtencionesEstanciaHospitalaria genero N registros (uno por día entre las fechas FechaOcupacion y FechaDesocupacion). Cada uno de estos registros tiene el id del servicio, el año, el mes y el día en que la cama estuvo ocupada por un determinado paciente.

Luego lo único que hay que hacer es agrupar por servicio, año y mes y contar la cantidad de registros (el total de camas ocupadas en el mes).

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT IdServicio, year(FechaOcupacion) AS anio, month(FechaOcupacion) AS mes,
           day(FechaOcupacion) AS dia,
           DATEADD(day, 1,  FechaOcupacion) AS FechaOcupacion,
           CAST(COALESCE(FechaDesocupacion, GETDATE()) AS date) AS FechaDesocupacion
    FROM AtencionesEstanciaHospitalaria

    UNION ALL

    SELECT IdServicio, year(FechaOcupacion) AS anio, month(FechaOcupacion) AS mes,
           day(FechaOcupacion) AS dia,
           DATEADD(day, 1,  FechaOcupacion) AS FechaOcupacion,
           FechaDesocupacion
    FROM cte
    WHERE FechaOcupacion <= FechaDesocupacion
)

SELECT IdServicio, anio, mes, count(*) AS CamasOcupadas
FROM cte
GROUP BY IdServicio, anio, mes
ORDER BY IdServicio, anio, mes;
```

Si se quisiera obtener el total de camas ocupadas cada día en cada servicio, lo que habría que hacer es agrupar también por el día.

Comment: Usar consultas recursivas para contar es una mala idea si queremos tener sistemas que funcionen de forma eficiente. Terminará siendo un problema de rendimiento por la cantidad de lecturas a la tabla que se realiza.